# How can I measure the quality of my software architecture?

Tags: architecture, osgi, software-design

I have a relatively complex software I have made, and now *I want to evaluate how "good" my architecture is. Is it modular? Is it simple? Could it be better? Where are the biggest flaws?*

The only metrics I know are Coupling and Cohesion. But I have nothing to compare them to (they are relative metrics right? Or are there any standards stating something like Coupling less than X is good, etc...).

Thanks!

**For the ones interested:**

**Coupling** - Measures the degree to which each program module relies on each one of the other modules. The greater the coupling is, more difficult is to modify or exchange some module without affecting other modules.

**Cohesion** - defines how well defined is some module’s responsibilities. If a module has an high cohesion, it means that this module has a well defined task, otherwise, the module does several tasks that don’t have much in common, which usually leads to system disorganization.

*There are several ways to calculate these metrics, but I know no standard way.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) detection to evaluate your code. You can find further discussion at this [question on programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49268/are-there-architecture-smells) regarding code smells for architecture.